Spelling Checker in TeXworks does not work
I installed English spell checking dictionary in TeXworks according to this answer. But after I selected the installed dictionary (Edit Menu -> Spelling -> English - United States (en_US)), the spelling checker seems not working for me. I said this because if I deliberately typed a wrong word, I thought there should be a red wavy line under the wrong Word，but there is no such line. So, what can I do to have the spelling checker work inside TeXworks? I am running TeXworks version 0.6.8 on Windows 10. Thanks.


Which answer? You linked a question with 8 answers.  I would start by installing hunspell.
